# Why calling the constructor from a WinRT component from C# Unity script results in NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, plugins, windows-runtime

I'm working on a Unity plugin which is a *C++/WinRT component* and when I try to access the runtime class from a *Unity C# script*, it throws *NullReferenceException*.
Here are the simplified contents of the component and the unity script I'm having problems with:

**WinRT RTClass.idl:**

```
namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    runtimeclass HelperClass
    {
        HelperClass();
        Int32 MyProperty;
    }

    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass RTClass
    {
        RTClass();
        Int32 MyProperty;
    }
}
```

**WinRT HelperClass.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "HelperClass.g.h"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    struct HelperClass: HelperClassT<HelperClass>
    {
        HelperClass();

        int32_t MyProperty();
        void MyProperty(int32_t value);
    };
}

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::factory_implementation
{
    struct HelperClass: HelperClassT<HelperClass, implementation::HelperClass>
    {
    };
}
```

**WinRT RTClass.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "RTClass.g.h"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    struct RTClass : RTClassT<RTClass>
    {
        RTClass();

        int32_t MyProperty();
        void MyProperty(int32_t value);
    };
}

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::factory_implementation
{
    struct RTClass : RTClassT<RTClass, implementation::RTClass>
    {
    };
}
```

**WinRT HelperClass.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "HelperClass.h"
#include "HelperClass.g.cpp"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    HelperClass::HelperClass()
    {
    }
    int32_t HelperClass::MyProperty()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void HelperClass::MyProperty(int32_t /* value */)
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }
}
```

**WinRT RTClass.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "RTClass.h"
#include "RTClass.g.cpp"

namespace winrt::RuntimeComponent1::implementation
{
    RTClass::RTClass()
    {
    // Do some stuff in the constructor
    }
    int32_t RTClass::MyProperty()
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }

    void RTClass::MyProperty(int32_t /* value */)
    {
        throw hresult_not_implemented();
    }
}
```

**Unity script:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
using RuntimeComponent1;
#endif

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
#if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
RTClass rt;
#endif

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        #if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT
    rt = new RTClass(); // <--- NullReferenceException here
    // ...
        #endif
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

The runtime component has more than 1 runtime classes and if I try to create an instance of the component's default class (RTClass) in the Unity script, it gives **NullReferenceException**.

The WinRT component is built for **ARM** architecture in **Debug mode**.
I use Unity **2021.3.27f1 LTS** but also tested it with **2022.3.3f1 LTS**, same results.
I copied the **.dll** and **.winmd** to **Unity Project Dir\Assets\Plugins\WSA\ARM** and set the **Platform Settings > CPU** to **ARM**. In the **Player Settings**, *Unsafe Code* is allowed, **Api compatibility level** is set to **.NET Framework.** The build platform is also set to **UWP** and the architecture is **ARM**.  What I think is the problem is on the winRT components side since intellisense does not complain in the C# script and Unity successfully compiles the project, the exception happens in runtime. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem by removing the **runtime class HelperClass** declaration from **RTClass.idl** and deleting **HelperClass.h** and **.cpp**. Then I created a new **View Model (C++/WinRT)** named **HelperClass** which generates and groups the **HelperClass.h** and **.cpp** under **HelperClass.idl**. By building this, it generated 2 **winmd** files (**RTClass.winmd** and **HelperClass.winmd**) but it also merged them under the root namespace **RuntimeComponent1.winmd**. Turns out with this approach, Unity doesn't complain about making a **new instance** of the runtime class.